# how would you ensure subscript element access is within the size limit of a heap container e.g vector in implementing a move_down_the_heap function?

Tags: c++, vector, heap, heapsort

the interface looks like this

```
template <class T, class Pred>
void downheap (std::vector<T>& heap_vector, unsigned int startingIndex, Pred predicateFunc);
```

if the *startingIndex* is at **k** in the vector, its **left child** in the heap will be located at index **(2 * k)** 
and its **right child** in the heap will be located at index **((2 * k )+ 1)**.
essentially, the item should be compared (and swapped as necessary) with its appropriate child in the 
heap until the given order by the predicate function has been satisfied.

the predicate might be greaterthan, lesserthan or any custom sequence...

in implementing such a method, how do you check that index access is within the size limit? i.e 
**heap_vector[rightChildIndex]** or **heap_vector[leftChildIndex]** should not go beyond **heap_vector.size()-1** while looping and doing comparison...
it has given me a bit of a headache

here is my code

```
 while ( pred ( heap_vector[rightChild], heap_vector[parentIndex] ) || pred (  
         heap_vector[leftChild], heap_vector[parentIndex] ) ) {

    if ( pred ( heap_vector[rightChild], heap_vector[leftChild]) ) {
        std::swap(heap_vector[parentIndex],heap_vector[rightChild]);
        parentIndex=rightChild;

    }       
    else {
        std::swap( heap_vector[parentIndex], heap_vector[leftChild]);
        parentIndex=leftChild;

    }

    rightChild= 2*parentIndex+1;
    leftChild=2*parentIndex;

    if (rightChild>heap_vector.size() || leftChild>heap_vector.size())
        break;
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i've tried a while loop.... that checks an if state

Comment: @joachim i've tried a while loop.... `while ( predicateFunc (heap_vector[richtChildIndex],heap_vector[parentIndex],) || pred (heap_vector[leftChildIndex],heap_vector[parentIndex],))` and at the very end of the while loop i have an if to ensure that the loop breaks when the calculated rightChildIndex and leftChildIndex are

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code and explanations.